# How many times all rows got effected when we update the array of row?

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

for every request we will update the array with in the record for every records, so i want to know how many times those records got effected.

ex:

column names : _id, data
with in data we have below jsonb object.

```
{
"_id": "57878787687gyhhg67676",

"uodateStatuses": [
    {
        "user": "user1",
        "timeStamp": 1551282618.419124        },
    {
        "user": "user1",
        "timeStamp": 1551282618.419124        },
    {
        "user": "user1",
        "timeStamp": 1551282618.419124        },
],
}
```

when we have like above data, for every request we are updating updateStatuses array with different time timestamp so finally we need to get how many times all records got effected.

expected output:

when we did update array of 10 records like

```
{
  "_id": "1",

  "uodateStatuses": [
  {
    "user": "user1",
    "timeStamp": 1551282618.419124        },
  ]
} - this one update

{
  "_id": "2",

  "uodateStatuses": [
  {
    "user": "user1",
    "timeStamp": 1551282618.419125       },
  ]
} - this second record update with different time stamp
```

like if we update 10 records then count will be 10 but if update again second entry will be available and count will be 20 that means 10 records effected two times for every record so total count will be 20.

if update n times then count will be 10 * n times right so i just want to know how can i write a query to achieve this in postgres sql.

if still this question is not clear, i will give more clarity again.

Thanks,

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. It's not clear what is your question, please read [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and improve your question, help us help you.

Comment: apologize  for not clear question post on the stackover flow, i have update the question again.

Comment: This would be sooo much easier with a properly normalized data model